# How to fire events using Bukkit API?

Tags: java, events, bukkit

I was looking at how to create and fire events using Bukkit API.

```
public class PlayerDisconnect implements Listener {
    @EventHandler
    public void onQuit(PlayerQuitEvent event){
        //code
    }
}
```

I mean, doesn't matter the name of the method (in this case `onQuit`, I can use `onDisconnect`, `onLeave`, etc. and it will still be called by `PlayerQuitEvent`), it calls every method using `PlayerQuitEvent` as a parameter. I want to be able to replicate that behaviour.

Comment: You can use any name for your listener method due to the `@EventHandler` annotation, in which it is targeting a method, so any name will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create and call your own custom events using the Bukkit Event API. Spigot has a good starting tutorial on the [Event API](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/using-the-event-api/).

A simple example of a `Cancellable` event that takes a `Player`:

```java
...
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.Cancellable;
import org.bukkit.event.Event;
import org.bukkit.event.HandlerList;

public class MyCustomEvent extends Event implements Cancellable
{
    private static final HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();

    private final Player player;
    private boolean cancelled;

    public MyCustomEvent(Player player)
    {
        this.player = player;
    }

    public static HandlerList getHandlerList()
    {
        return handlers;
    }

    public Player getPlayer()
    {
        return this.player;
    }

    public HandlerList getHandlers()
    {
        return handlers;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCancelled() 
    {
        return cancelled;
    }

    @Override
    public void setCancelled(boolean cancelled) 
    {
        this.cancelled = cancelled;
    }

}
```

Which you can then call elsewhere in your custom event like so

```java
...
MyCustomEvent event = new MyCustomEvent(player);
Bukkit.getPluginManager().callEvent(event);
if (event.isCancelled())
    return;
...
```

Finally, you would listen for the event like you would any other event:

```java
...
@EventHandler
public void onMyCustomEvent(MyCustomEvent event){
    Player player = event.getPlayer();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`PluginManager#callEvent(Event)`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/plugin/PluginManager.html#callEvent(org.bukkit.event.Event)).

```
public class CustomEvent extends Event implements Cancellable {
    private static final HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();

    private final String a;
    private final int b;
    private boolean cancelled;

    public CustomEvent(String a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public int getB() {
        return b;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCancelled() {
        return cancelled;
    }
 
    @Override
    public void setCancelled(boolean cancelled) {
        this.cancelled = cancelled;
    }

    @Override
    public HandlerList getHandlers() {
        return handlers;
    }

    public static HandlerList getHandlerList() {
        return handlers;
    }
}
```

```
CustomEvent event = new CustomEvent("some data", 5);
Server server = ...
server.getPluginManager().callEvent(event);
if (event.isCancelled()) return;
// Do event
```

See [the official tutorial](https://bukkit.fandom.com/wiki/Event_API_Reference#Creating_Custom_Events) and [this community tutorial](https://bukkit.org/threads/tutorial-adding-custom-events.178222/).

---

If you want to use the Bukkit event system in a non-Bukkit plugin project, you can add the Bukkit API as dependency (just the API, not the server implementing it).